# Multiple headers in angular post request cause an error

Tags: angularjs, post, header

I have a problem with adding multiple headers to a post request in Angular. My code looks like this:

```
main.factory('Login', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        authorize: function (username, password, api_url) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: api_url + '/api/auth/authorize',
                transformRequest: function (obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for (var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: { username: username, password: password }
            });
        }
    };
});

main.run(function ($http) {

    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Testing'] = 'hello';

});
```

For some reason I get an internal angular error that says "Method not valid" from the `createHttpBackend` function (Angular function) when it try to do `xhr.send(post);` If I comment out `$http.defaults.headers.post['Testing'] = 'hello';` Everything works perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea why this happen? Please tell me if there is any code you might find it useful to look at.

PS: It does not make a difference if I add the last header to post or common, still same error.

Comment: did you find out that was happening. I'm struggling In same problem, When I add multiple header, It does not send data at server side.